# Hide form labels using django-allauth and crispy form

Tags: django-allauth, django-crispy-forms

I use django-allauth and crispy forms to customize my login form. Everything works fine without any problems. The only issue is that I am not able to hide the form labels.

I dont want to use javascript to hide the label fields. Would be nice to be able to do this from python.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

**forms.py** (override of allauth login form)

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from allauth.account.forms import LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django import forms


class UserLoginForm(LoginForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

**settings.py**

```
...
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'login': 'user.forms.UserLoginForm'}
...
```

**lohin.html**

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}

<form class="login" method="POST" action="{% url 'account_login' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {{ form|crispy }}

  <a class="..." href="">...</a>
  <button class="..." type="submit">{...</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**UPDATE**

I ended doing it like this:

```
class UserLoginForm(LoginForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False

        self.fields["login"].label = ""
        self.fields["password"].label = ""
```

**But why `self.helper.form_show_labels = False` doesn't work?**

Answer (score 1):

Yeah i have faced the same problem, i don't know why **FormHelper()** class from crispy forms don't works.But i found a solution, its a simple solution from css.If you see the inspector in browser for crispy forms, crispy forms use **.requiredField** class to display the label.so, you want to override the class using css.

```css
.requiredField{
  display: none;
}
```

**Please note that in future crispy forms may change the class, so in every update of crispy form check the class in browser inspector.**